# Trying to get the item id to my another function

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I am trying my new shopping cart with myself . .  I know this is very basic question But I am stucking here pls clarify my doubt.

Shall I get the item id to my another function?
if i alert this id value in my addto_cart function it is showing [object MouseEvent]
how can I get the Id of my items to the another my function(addto_cart)

```
<header class="page-header header container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-9"></div>
<div class="col-md-3 cart_icon"><img src="images\shopping_64.png" width="50px" height="50px"></div>
</div>
</header>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="icecream_box">
<ul id="item_list">
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>



const items=[
{
    id:1,
    name:"vannila Ice cream",
    price:80,
    image_url:"images/vannila_ice.jpg"

},
{
    id:2,
    name:"Choclate Ice cream",
    price:120,
    image_url:"images/Chocolate-ice.jpg"

},
{
    id:3,
    name:"Strawberry Ice cream",
    price:100,
    image_url:"images/strawberry_ice.jpg"

},
{
    id:4,
    name:"Caramel Ice cream",
    price:180,
    image_url:"images/caramel.jpg"

}



];

var ulvar=document.getElementById("item_list");
items.forEach(loop_item);
function loop_item(item,index)
{
    //document.getElementsByClassName("icecream_box")[0].innerHTML=item.name;
    var btn_add=document.createElement("button");
    var list=document.createElement("li");
    list.innerHTML=`<img class="item_images" src="${item.image_url}" width="200px" Height="200px">
    <div>${item.name}</div>
    <div>Rs.${item.price}</div>
    <div id="id_get">${item.id}</div>
    <button type="button" class="btn-primary shop_btn">SHOP</button>
    `;
    
    ulvar.appendChild(list);
    list.className+="list_cls";
    
    console.log(item.name);
}
var btn=document.getElementsByClassName("shop_btn");
for (var i = 0 ; i < btn.length; i++) {
 btn[i].addEventListener("click",addto_cart);  
}

function addto_cart(id)
{

alert(id);
}
```

My full code is here Pls look this
https://codepen.io/pavisaran/pen/poeEvNv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add data attributes (`data-id-clicked="${item.id}"`) on the button when creating button and get an id using on click of the button

```
<button type="button" class="btn-primary shop_btn" data-id-clicked="${item.id}">SHOP</button>
```

**Access id**

```
function addto_cart(e) {
    const id = e.target.dataset.idClicked;
    alert(id);
}
```

```js
const items = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "vannila Ice cream",
    price: 80,
    image_url: "images/vannila_ice.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Choclate Ice cream",
    price: 120,
    image_url: "images/Chocolate-ice.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Strawberry Ice cream",
    price: 100,
    image_url: "images/strawberry_ice.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Caramel Ice cream",
    price: 180,
    image_url: "images/caramel.jpg",
  },
];

var ulvar = document.getElementById("item_list");
items.forEach(loop_item);

function loop_item(item, index) {
  //document.getElementsByClassName("icecream_box")[0].innerHTML=item.name;
  var btn_add = document.createElement("button");
  var list = document.createElement("li");
  list.innerHTML = `<img class="item_images" src="${item.image_url}" width="200px" Height="200px">
    <div>${item.name}</div>
    <div>Rs.${item.price}</div>
    <div id="id_get">${item.id}</div>
    <button type="button" class="btn-primary shop_btn" data-id-clicked="${item.id}">SHOP</button>
    `;

  ulvar.appendChild(list);
  list.className += "list_cls";

  console.log(item.name);
}
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("shop_btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener("click", addto_cart);
}

function addto_cart(e) {
  const id = e.target.dataset.idClicked;
  alert(id);
}
```

```html
<header class="page-header header container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 cart_icon"><img src="images\shopping_64.png" width="50px" height="50px"></div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="icecream_box">
        <ul id="item_list">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it is working!! I have tried both of your answers 
@decpk & julien.giband both are working fine

Answer (score 0):

An event handler takes the `event` as argument. To retrieve the element that triggered the event, use `event.target`.

```js
function addto_cart(event)
{
  alert(event.target.id);
}
```

In your partcular case, you need to climb up the DOM to your button's parent, then find the `<div>` with id `id_get` and read its text content.

Use `closest` to find a parent with a given selector, and `querySelector` to easily find a given element within that.

```js
const items = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "vannila Ice cream",
    price: 80,
    image_url: "https://picsum.photos/seed/product1/200"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Choclate Ice cream",
    price: 120,
    image_url: "https://picsum.photos/seed/product2/200"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Strawberry Ice cream",
    price: 100,
    image_url: "https://picsum.photos/seed/product3/200"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Caramel Ice cream",
    price: 180,
    image_url: "https://picsum.photos/seed/product4/200"
  }
];

const ulvar = document.getElementById("item_list");
items.forEach(loop_item);

function loop_item(item, index) {
  //document.getElementsByClassName("icecream_box")[0].innerHTML=item.name;
  const btn_add = document.createElement("button");
  const list = document.createElement("li");
  list.innerHTML = `<img class="item_images" src="${item.image_url}" width="200px" Height="200px">
    <div>${item.name}</div>
    <div>Rs.${item.price}</div>
    <div id="id_get">${item.id}</div>
    <button type="button" class="btn-primary shop_btn">SHOP</button>
    `;

  ulvar.appendChild(list);
  list.className += "list_cls";

  console.log(item.name);
}
const btn = document.getElementsByClassName("shop_btn");
for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener("click", addto_cart);
}

function addto_cart(event) {
  const btn = event.target;
  const div = btn.closest('li').querySelector('#id_get');
  alert(div.textContent);
}
```

```html
<header class="page-header header container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 cart_icon"><img src="https://p.kindpng.com/picc/s/714-7147174_png-file-svg-transparent-background-shopping-cart-icon.png" width="50px" height="50px"></div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="icecream_box">
        <ul id="item_list">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `event.target.id` gives empty string. Since there is no attributes as `id`.

Comment: OK answered too fast. I added what was necessary into a runnable snippet with detailed explanations

Comment: Thanks it is working!! I have tried both of your answers @decpk & julien.giband both are working fine

Comment: @Pavi_Web great. I'm just pointing out something more: you create multiple items with `id="id_get"`. You shouldn't: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id. Use a `class` there instead, or make the `id` unique

Comment: @julien.giband  Yes I can understand it. . and tried in all the way . . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `index` of the current targetted `item` to the function and get the item id after getting the item with that index.

See the code:

```js
const items = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "vannila Ice cream",
    price: 80,
    image_url: "images/vannila_ice.jpg"

  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Choclate Ice cream",
    price: 120,
    image_url: "images/Chocolate-ice.jpg"

  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Strawberry Ice cream",
    price: 100,
    image_url: "images/strawberry_ice.jpg"

  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Caramel Ice cream",
    price: 180,
    image_url: "images/caramel.jpg"

  }



];

var ulvar = document.getElementById("item_list");
items.forEach(loop_item);

function loop_item(item, index) {
  //document.getElementsByClassName("icecream_box")[0].innerHTML=item.name;
  var btn_add = document.createElement("button");
  var list = document.createElement("li");
  list.innerHTML = `<img class="item_images" src="${item.image_url}" width="200px" Height="200px">
    <div>${item.name}</div>
    <div>Rs.${item.price}</div>
    <div id="id_get">${item.id}</div>
    <button type="button" class="btn-primary shop_btn">SHOP</button>
    `;

  ulvar.appendChild(list);
  list.className += "list_cls";

}
var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".shop_btn");
for (let i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].addEventListener("click", e => {
    addto_cart(i)
  });
}

function addto_cart(ind) {
  //want to add the items into my cart if i click the shop button
  console.log(items[ind])
  console.log('ID: ', items[ind].id)
}
```

```css
header
{
    height: 56px;
    /* //background-color: #db4cff; */
    background:linear-gradient(to right, #45166a, #83157b 75%, #bc158a);
}
.cart_icon
{
    float:right;
    
}
li
{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
}
.list_cls
{
    padding:0px 20px;
}
.shop_btn
{
    background-color: #72f4bf;
    color: #45166a;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="page-header header container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-9"></div>
<div class="col-md-3 cart_icon"><img src="images\shopping_64.png" width="50px" height="50px"></div>
</div>
</header>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="icecream_box">
<ul id="item_list">

</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nh1bx6e7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameter to you eventListener

```js
const items=[
{
    id:1,
    name:"vannila Ice cream",
    price:80,
    image_url:"images/vannila_ice.jpg"

},
{
    id:2,
    name:"Choclate Ice cream",
    price:120,
    image_url:"images/Chocolate-ice.jpg"

},
{
    id:3,
    name:"Strawberry Ice cream",
    price:100,
    image_url:"images/strawberry_ice.jpg"

},
{
    id:4,
    name:"Caramel Ice cream",
    price:180,
    image_url:"images/caramel.jpg"

}



];

var ulvar=document.getElementById("item_list");
items.forEach(loop_item);
function loop_item(item,index)
{
    //document.getElementsByClassName("icecream_box")[0].innerHTML=item.name;
    var btn_add=document.createElement("button");
    var list=document.createElement("li");
    list.innerHTML=`<img class="item_images" src="${item.image_url}" width="200px" Height="200px">
    <div>${item.name}</div>
    <div>Rs.${item.price}</div>
    <div id="id_get">${item.id}</div>
    <button type="button" class="btn-primary shop_btn">SHOP</button>
    `;
    
    ulvar.appendChild(list);
    list.className+="list_cls";
    
    console.log(item.name);
}
var btn=document.querySelectorAll(".shop_btn");
btn.forEach((f,index)=>{
 f.addEventListener("click", function(){
    addto_cart(items[index]);
}, false)
})
console.log(btn)
for (var i = 0 ; i < btn.length; i++) {
;  

}

function addto_cart(item)
{
//want to add the items into my cart if i click the shop button

  alert(item.name)
  //console.log(e)
//alert(id);    
}
```

```css
header
{
    height: 56px;
    /* //background-color: #db4cff; */
    background:linear-gradient(to right, #45166a, #83157b 75%, #bc158a);
}
.cart_icon
{
    float:right;
    
}
li
{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
}
.list_cls
{
    padding:0px 20px;
}
.shop_btn
{
    background-color: #72f4bf;
    color: #45166a;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="page-header header container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-9"></div>
<div class="col-md-3 cart_icon"><img src="images\shopping_64.png" width="50px" height="50px"></div>
</div>
</header>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="icecream_box">
<ul id="item_list">

</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```